# JQuery - two overlaping/colliding Scripts

Tags: jquery, collision, overlap

I just started to redesign my Portfolio an found a tiny annoying bug:
Please have a look at http://hire.pixelpizza.de/ and click on "ok, lets see the goods". after that, you will have a page with a blue background and there you have to click on "see more pictures of the west". now you have opened up a fancybox Gallery.

The problem is, now the two Scripts for the Page Switch and for the Fancybox are coliding and overlaping each other if you press the right arrow button on your keyboard and thats not so cool

i have absolutly no clue how to fix that :-/ i just want that the hander.js (http://hire.pixelpizza.de/assets/js/handler.js) Script Stops when i open up the fancy box and start again when i close them. its kinda tricky because both scripts are using the key number 39

i could also live with a solution where you cant use the left and right keys at all when you open up the fancybox but the site-switch think have to stop when the fancybox apears

Answer (score 1):

In the source of fancybox you'll find this at line 671:

```
if (keys) {
  D.bind('keydown.fb', function (e) {
    var code   = e.which || e.keyCode,
                 target = e.target || e.srcElement;
// more code
  });
}
```

Change it into:

```
if (keys) {
  D.bind('keydown.fb', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var code   = e.which || e.keyCode,
                 target = e.target || e.srcElement;
// more code
  });
}
```

And the event will stop bubbling through the rest of the script. Nice website btw

Comment: Thank you :) and thank you for your help!
but it doesent work :/ i change the line (http://hire.pixelpizza.de/source/jquery.fancybox.js) but both things are keep scrolling if i press the right button